# Solving intersect and union formula between four sets

Tags: set, set-intersection, set-union

I am trying to figure out how ( b ^ cd ^ ab ) is converted to ( bc u bd ), can anyone one explain to me how the first formula was converted to the second one?

As shown in the photo below:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure about the missing `a` in the second formula?

Comment: Thats it exactly what is written in the notes

Comment: What notes? Are you sure of the credibility of the notes? Any assumptions about variable a and others?

Comment: I've added the whole slide